Adjacent vs. All-Possible Distances in the Definition of a Cauchy Sequence
I'm currently learning about Cauchy sequences, and I'm trying to build my intuition regarding its definition. My question is on how we can motivate why we consider the distances between all points and every other point, that is, for all $m$ and $n$ greater than some $N$, $[d(m,n)\leq \epsilon]$, instead of the distance between all points and its neighbor, that is, for all $m$ greater than $M$, $[d(m, m+1)\leq \epsilon]$. The former (i.e., proper) definition seems more unwieldy.
I think one way to motivate this is to provide counterexamples of divergent rational sequences with adjacent terms that get very (i.e., infinitesimally) close to each other further down the sequence. But I can't think of any. The closest I seem to get is the real sequence $f(n)=log(n)$, but that's not a rational sequence. (The aim is to build the real numbers from the notion of a Cauchy sequence so it's illegal to talk about real sequences when we're still defining a Cauchy sequence).
Just to lay out the intuition I have so far...
Essentially, a Cauchy sequence has terms that get very (i.e., infinitesimally) close to each other, and the epsilon-delta definition is a formulation of this idea in purely logical terms with no invocation of the concept of infinity (like how mathematical induction handles infinity by considering some arbitrary particular $n$ and its successor).
So, a sequence is Cauchy if, no matter how fine a precision/distance $\epsilon$ you can think of, I can cut the sequence off at some point $N$ and every point $m, n$ to the right of $N$ have distances between each other that are smaller than $\epsilon$. However, it just seems conceptually unwieldy to consider so many distances (if we think combinatorially, you gotta imagine tons of possible distances). Why can't we just consider distances between adjacent points instead? For the sequence $f(n)=1/n$, the smallest distance a point has with any other point is between that and its neighbor, so a neighboring-distance definition would work. But are there cases where this neighboring-distance definition would break down?

The $f(n) = \log n$ example is a good example that illustrates the deficiencies in the adjacent points definition. If you really want it to be rational, you could just strategically truncate the $\log n$ decimal expansions. Or you could use the classic example: $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$.

"it just seems conceptually unwieldy to consider so many distances (if we think combinatorially [sic], you gotta imagine tons of possible distances)" - either way, you will need to consider a countably infinite collection of distances, so this point isn't really true.

$0,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2,2.01,2.02,2.03,\dots,2.97,2.98,2.99,3,3.001,3.002,\dots$

Thanks for all the help and examples guys!
